# Работа с Map с применением Stream Api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Имеется `Map<SomeKey, List<SomeObject>>`, необходимо при помощи Stream Api сначала получить все списки из значений, а затем объединить их в один список, чтобы в конце можно было добавить все эти элементы в другую коллекцию.

```
.forEach(x -> someList.add(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<SomeObject> l = map.values().stream() // Stream<List<SomeObject>>
        .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<SomeObject>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

flatMap принимает функцию, которая создает Stream c произвольным числом элементов в нём для каждого входного значения, элементы из получившихся стримов в итоге объединяются в один Stream.

В данном случае каждый лист в потоке превращается в поток элементов данного листа, и все элементы всех листов становятся одним потоком, который дальше мы просто собираем в лист.

Comment: Можете пояснить, как "потоки объединяются в исходный stream"?

Comment: @ДмитрийНикифоров исправил, надеюсь сейчас лучше. Новое описание не принял, потому что хотел оставить общее описание flatMap, а не только для листа. Если есть идеи как улучшить, то дайте знать